# Synonym for take for granted attitude

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am writing an essay on food wastage. I  was writing a line

> *The take for granted attitude of people towards food is a very sad reality of todays world where millions of people sleep hungry every night.*

Is there any word which I can use here. I have looked for synonyms but none seems to fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it fits very good in the sentence. For better clarity, I would spell it with hyphens: "*take-for-granted* attitude".

Additionally, I would make a few other changes:

> The **take-for-granted attitude** of people towards food is a very sad reality of **today's** world, where millions of people **go to** sleep hungry every night.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **take for granted** is pretty good- you could hyphenate it, as virolino suggests.

If you want a single word, the word [**entitled**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/entitled) has come to have a similar meaning in recent times.

Comment: I understand your intention with "entitled", but how would you use it in the sentence? Obviously the structure of the sentence would change, but what about the meaning?

Comment: @virolino just replace **take for granted** with **entitled**.